# How hive understands the size of input data?

Tags: apache, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to understand Hive internals. What class/method hive uses to understand size of dataset in S3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive is built on top of hadoop, and uses hadoop's HDFS as API for input/output. 
More precisely, it has a InputFormat and OutputFormat that are configurable when you create a table that get data from a FileSystem object (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileSystem.html). 
The FileSystem object abstracts most aspects of file management, so hive does not have to worry if a file is on S3 or HDFS as the hadoop/HDFS layer takes care of that. 
When dealing with files, each file has a path that is a URL (for instance, hdfs:///dir/file or s3:///bucket/path ).
The `Path` class resolves the filesystem using the [getFileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/Path.html#getFileSystem%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) method, which would be [S3FileSystem](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3/S3FileSystem.html) for an S3 url.
 From the FileSystem object, it can get the file size using the methods for [`FileStatus`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/FileStatus.html) using the `getLen` method.

If you want to see where in the hive source this is done, it is usually in `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.CombineHiveInputFormat` which is the default setting for `hive.input.format`.